# Erro em consulta no banco com Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, winforms, linq

Boa noite!
Estou tentado realizar uma consulta em uma tabela mysql, utilizando linq, e apresentar esse resultado em uma gridview para o usuário. Tenho a tabela abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não estou buscando todas as colunas desta tabela, apenas algumas para isso estou usando o código abaixo na minha classe ManipulaDados:

```
public GridView exibeCarteira(string cepf, GridView tb)
    {
        try
        {
            bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();

            var crt = from cart in bc.carteira
                      where cart.cpf == cepf
                      select new
                      {
                          Código = cart.codigo,
                          Valor = cart.valoracao,
                          Quantidade = cart.qtdacao,
                          Total = cart.vtotalacao,
                          Investido = cart.vinvestido,
                          ValorTotal = cart.vtotalacao
                      };
            tb.DataSource = crt;
            tb.DataBind();
            return tb;
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());

        }

    }
```

este método é chamado por um método de outra classe o método é esse:

```
 public GridView mostraCarteira(string cpf, GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            ManipulaBanco mp = new ManipulaBanco();
            return mp.exibeCarteira(cpf, gv);
        }
        catch (Exception e4)
        {

            throw new Exception(e4.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Para testar esse meto estou utilizando a classe Web abaixo:

```
 public partial class ExibeCarteira : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cpf;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                exibirCarteira();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw new Exception(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void exibirCarteira()
    {
        try
        {
            Trataformes tf = new Trataformes();
            this.gvcarteira = tf.mostraCarteira(cpf, gvcarteira);

        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {

            throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void gvcarteira_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }}
```

Quando compilo recebo o erro abaixo que não estou conseguindo solucionar, alguém pode me ajudar?

> Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Comment: Não sei o erro, se tem ai para passar! outra coisa `Código` com acentuação, não é uma boa prática !!! e talvez seja o erro!

Comment: Ops. Faltou passar o erro : Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery, DbRawSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList(). For ASP.NET WebForms you can bind to the result of calling ToList() on the query or use Model Binding, for more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=389592.

Comment: faltou se dar um ToList() em crt, coloquei uma resposta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chame `ToList()` ou `ToArray()` na variável `crt`, porque, o `DataSource` precisa de um enumeração. Mudei seu método sendo o `tb` (`GridView`) variável por referência fica mais prático, mas poderia ser por retorno.

```
public void exibeCarteira(string cepf, ref GridView tb)
{
    try
    {
        bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();
        var crt = from cart in bc.carteira
                  where cart.cpf == cepf
                  select new
                  {
                      Código = cart.codigo,
                      Valor = cart.valoracao,
                      Quantidade = cart.qtdacao,
                      Total = cart.vtotalacao,
                      Investido = cart.vinvestido,
                      ValorTotal = cart.vtotalacao
                  };
        tb.DataSource = crt.ToList();
        tb.DataBind();      
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        throw new Exception(e1.Message.ToString());

    }
}
```

---

Como usar:

```
Trataformes tf = new Trataformes();
tf.mostraCarteira(cpf, ref gvcarteira);
```

***Obs:*** Troque `Código` (com acentuação) para `Codigo` (sem acentuação) seria uma boa prática

Comment: Fiz as modificações que você falou, não deu erro,  mas acho que faltou algo pois não esta exibindo.

Comment: Dá um breakpoint nessa linha `tb.DataSource = crt.ToList();` e verifique se teve retorno?

Comment: OK, funcionou o que estava ocorrendo era que eu não estava adicionando um valor pra o CPF, então ele não conseguia me retornar valor nenhum.  Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @user9090, legal ...